# How to add a title header to a GridView?

Tags: java, android, gridview, layout

**I am trying to make the following layout:**

http://oi57.tinypic.com/zuqwew.jpg

But the problem here is that there is no option by default to add a header above the GridView.

**Here is what I have done so far:**

http://oi59.tinypic.com/zwxc2s.jpg

Is there any way to put a header which will scroll along the grid view horizontally? (Yes, it SHOULD scroll). I tried to make the first row permanently display the header content but no luck. Please help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rather than GridView use ListView and above use some some static layout or you can use sticky Header ListView library
https://github.com/applidium/HeaderListView

Comment: I had read that, but how can i use a listview to display grid data? I mean how can I manage displaying those columns?

Comment: just create one custom row item that look like grid row  and rest will be the same

Comment: my personal view is it better to use listview here compare to gridview in this situation...